# How can I add name of parent node to first child xsl?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this xml file.

**Xml input file**

```
<Node Name="A100" Id="0x1" Type="1" >
<First Name="First" Val0="0" Val1="8" Val2="3" Val3="4" Val4="8" Val5="3" Val6="4">
<Second Name="N1" Val0="7" Val1="3"/>
<Second Name="N2" Val0="0" Val1="2"/>
<Second Name="N3" Val0="NoFunction" Val1="ab"/>
<Second Name="N4" Val0="0" Val1="xy"/>
</First>
<Second Name="N5" Val="No"/>
<Second Name="N6" Val="No" />
<Second Name="N7" Val="No" />
</Node>
<Node Name="B200" Id="0x2" Type="1" >
<First Name="First" Val0="0" Val1="8" Val2="7" Val3="8" Val4="5" Val5="1" Val6="0">
<Second Name="N1" Val0="7" Val1="3"/>
<Second Name="N2" Val0="0" Val1="2"/>
<Second Name="N3" Val0="NoFunction" Val1="ab"/>
<Second Name="N4" Val0="0" Val1="xy"/>
</First>
<Second Name="N5" Val="No"/>
<Second Name="N6" Val="No" />
<Second Name="N7" Val="No" />
</Node>
```

I need to transform in another xml file using xsl like this:

**Xml output file**

```
 <Node Name="A100" Id="0x1" Type="1" >
<First Name="First" New="A100" Val0="0" Val1="8" Val2="3" Val3="4" Val4="8" Val5="3" Val6="4">
<Second Name="N1" Val0="7" Val1="3"/>
<Second Name="N2" Val0="0" Val1="2"/>
<Second Name="N3" Val0="NoFunction" Val1="ab"/>
<Second Name="N4" Val0="0" Val1="xy"/>
</First>
<Second Name="N5" Val="No"/>
<Second Name="N6" Val="No" />
<Second Name="N7" Val="No" />
</Node>
<Node Name="B200" Id="0x2" Type="1" >
<First Name="First" New="B200" Val0="0" Val1="8" Val2="7" Val3="8" Val4="5" Val5="1" Val6="0">
<Second Name="N1" Val0="7" Val1="3"/>
<Second Name="N2" Val0="0" Val1="2"/>
<Second Name="N3" Val0="NoFunction" Val1="ab"/>
<Second Name="N4" Val0="0" Val1="xy"/>
</First>
<Second Name="N5" Val="No"/>
<Second Name="N6" Val="No" />
<Second Name="N7" Val="No" />
</Node>
```

I want name of Node to be in First like New=@Name of Node.
Can anyone help me with this? Thank you

Comment: Have you tried any sample so far of XSLT? Using XSLT-1.0 or XSLT-2.0?

Answer (score 1):

You should learn about the [XSLT Identity Template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform)

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This will cater for all then nodes and attributes you wish to copy across unchanged. Then, all you need is a template that matches the `First` element, and adds a new attribute to it...

```
<xsl:template match="First">
    <First New="{../@Name}">
```

Note the use of curly braces, which indicate an [Attribute Value Template](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates), and so will be evaluated as an expression, rather than output literally.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="First">
        <First New="{../@Name}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </First>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is working great. Thank you a lot for information